# RegEx: Remove pattern and everything after it

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have strings with tags `<p>` and `</p>`   I want to just get everything inbetween the tags but not the tags themselves.

I have gotten one half of the RegEx to work:  `^[^_]*<p>`    This gives me the beginning but I still need another RegEx to get rid of `</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using lookbehind and lookahead to keep tags out of match and using `/s` modifier so that . matches also newlines

```
(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)
```

otherwise without /s modifier

```
(?<=<p>)[\s\S]*?(?=</p>)
```

because if perl can be shortended using \K, still to keep out of match

```
<p>\K.*?(?=</p>)
```

Comment: Hi Nahuel.  I changed your first expression to (?<=<p>)(.*)?(?=</p>)  This way it creates something for Alteryx to know what to parse.  Thank you it works!

Comment: `(.*)?`  is not the same thing that `.*?` lazy quantifier [see regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Q2SgFc/1/), maybe you mean `(.*?)`

Answer (score 2):

In case the tag `p` has any attributes (e.g. `<p class="foo">`) you may want to take the part on the right of `<p.*?>` instead. In this case you cannot use the lookbehind operator, because the expression involved does not have fixed length (the lookahead operator does not have such limitations, although that does not make any difference here). On the other hand, the keep operator `\K` works just fine after any expression.

Thus Nahuel's answer can be improved as follows (not counting the observation on including newlines)

```
    <p.*?>\K.*?(?=<\/p>)
```

Comment: This is elegant.  Thank you/

Comment: good, but because > is one character `[^>]*` will be more efficient than `.*?` inside p tag